# Python lab - I'm stuck with my code for my lab

Tags: python-2.7

My lab asks me "Prompt for the input of a number, accept either a positive or negative number.Use a dual alternative "decision" structure and print a message indicating whether the number entered is positive or negative."

I did my code but for some reason its not working....

```
def getNumFromUser():
  num=input (“Please enter a number: “)
  if num >= 0:
      print "The number you entered  is positive"
  elif num  <= 0:
      print "The number you entered is negative"
  else:
     getNumFromUser()
```

And it won't run my code for some reason,  when I take out elif statement it ask me to enter number and if I enter negative it will ask me to re-enter number to get positive ...I just don't know how to combine negative and positive number in code so it would "print out message indicating whether the number entered is positive or negative." ****I'm new to python programming so I'm lost here, I would appreciate if someone would explain to me****

Comment: What editor are you using to type your code btw? You have odd characters for the quotes around the input() string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `input` function in python2.x will try and evaluate the string you pass it as code. This can be considered undesirable or dangerous, and it is usually recommended to use `raw_input` instead.

That being said, `raw_input` will give you back a string. You will want to convert it to an int to compare to other ints:

```
val_str = raw_input("enter a number")
if int(val_str) >= 0:
    print "greater"
```

Keep in mind that if the user does not enter a number, that example would crash. You can check that a string is a number by using:  `val_str.isdigit()`. This works for ints, not floats. Part of your check can be to first confirm it is an int, otherwise ask again. Also, `isdigit` won't properly detect a negative number, which means you might want to learn how to catch an exception that can get raised...

As for your overall structure, I feel a simply `while` loop check would serve you better than a recursive call to `getNumFromUser` each time they enter bad information:

```
def getNumFromUser():

    while True:
        num=raw_input("Please enter a number: ")
        try:
            num = int(num)
        except ValueError:
            # if the input cannot be converted into an int
            # then loop again
            continue
        else:
            # otherwise, we have an int, so stop looping
            break

    # num is now an int
    if num >= 0:
        print "The number you entered  is positive"
    else:
        print "The number you entered is negative"

    return num
```

It may not be part of your assignment to expect the user to enter anything other than a valid `int`, but this example shows how to try and convert to int, and handle the failure.

Comment: jdi thank you for explaining let me try to finish this assignment and to see how it will work.....

Comment: Jdi I did my code with simple while loop it give me negative and positive number. However I don't know how to end the program, for example after user entered negative for the first try, and for the second try positive, the program should close but mine keep asking enter number...        while True:
    num = input("Please enter a number: ")
    if num >= 0: 
        print  " The number you entered is positive"   
    else:
        print "The number you entered is negative"

Comment: You need to use the `break` keyword to tell your while loop to end at the point you want.

Comment: I did but it gives me error it keep saying that break don't belong there

Comment: You will need to update your question with the example you are trying so that I can see the formatted code. Something is not correct.

Comment: never mind lol I added break outside the loop...i got it thank you so much for helping me out

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to hit the checkmark next to the answer that ended up solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
num=raw_input(“Please enter a number: “)
```

instead

Comment: I am not sure why people are voting this up. Simply using raw_input alone is not enough. It will return a string to which the OP is still making comparisons to an int. Even though its to `0`, it should still be noted that it can cause problems with other numeric comparisons.

Comment: @jdi:- Really you deserve more but,perhaps they are following shorter is sweeter...and for avoiding spoon feeding. ;)

Comment: Yea this does solve the immediate problem in making it not crash when its non-numeric. Hopefully the OP doesn't change the range of numbers to compare at any point.

Comment: I think OP should get another hard time to figure it out by himself for the crash... BTW +1 :)

Comment: So I shouldn't be using def getNumFromUser ():?

Answer (score 0):

make sure there is no space between the input and parenthesis.  You wrote this: 
num=input (“Please enter a number: “)
when you should have been writing this:
num = input("Please enter a number: ")
this will evaluate a string.  there is no need to add the raw part, at least in my experience programming with python